# What is the purpose of 'pure' keyword in the clash tutorial example?

Tags: haskell, hdl, clash

In Clash official website, there is the following example :

```
>>> sampleN @System 4 (register 0 (pure (8 :: Signed 8)))
```

I know what is a pure function, but why this keyword here ? If I remove it I got an error :

```
Clash.Prelude> sampleN @System 4 (register 0 (8 :: Signed 8))

<interactive>:2:32: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Signal System a'
                  with actual type `Signed 8'
    * In the second argument of `register', namely `(8 :: Signed 8)'
      In the third argument of `sampleN', namely
        `(register 0 (8 :: Signed 8))'
      In the expression: sampleN @System 4 (register 0 (8 :: Signed 8))
    * Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
```

Any clue ?

Comment: [`pure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure)  is not a keyword, it is just another function, taking a `Signed 8` and returning a value of type `Signal System a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Signal` has an instance of `Applicative` to which `pure` belongs. `pure :: a -> Signal dom a` lifts a value of type `Signed 8` to `Signal dom (Signed 8)`. Which unifies with `Signal System a` in that context to result in `Signal System (Signed 8)`.

Reference used: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.0.0/docs/Clash-Signal.html